# "Much more simple" or "much more simpler"

Tags: comparatives

Which is the correct sentence?

> It is much more simple to resolve the  memory leak issues.
>
> It is much more simpler to resolve the memory leak issues.

Comment: _Much simpler_ or _much more simple_. One or the other, not both.

Comment: "More" provides the comparative degree. With *more* you don't need *simpler*. This question is better suited to [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Where hopefully you'll be directed to a reference such as [here](https://eflnet.com/tutorials/adjcompsup.php)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may say either "more simple" or "simpler", but both together are redundant.

Comment: Thank you very more mucher! (Or is is *much morer*?)